# Best way to get data from server using Android Emulator

Tags: android, database

Am developing Android program. Now I need to access MSSQL2008R2 remotely from one computer(client) to another computer(server).

Which is the best way to connect?

Such as, `JDBC Driver`, `Web Service`

Comment: Imran man,, Please stop asking the same question again and again and again this is the third question you have asked regarding same problem. Have look at the FAQs. These types of activities will result you in loosing the privilege to ask question.

Comment: still there is no solution for my problem..i sent u last update.

Comment: See I was using a remote MySQL database for my android project. I was using a free host. I never had any problem connecting to the server I was using JSON there are thousands of people who disagree with using JDBC in android. Using a webservice is better so use it if you have any problem using it search for a while still u cnt find answer then you may ask here you will definitely get help. Take my request and spend some time on web services your problems will be solved very easily and you will be amazed.

Comment: Thank you mam, I will do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you developing the the mobile application for any OS like Android, iPhone, Blackberry etc. then you should use web service to get data from server.

Reason to use `Web service`.

If you use web services method to get the data from database server remain same and need to write once in webservice but in case of JDBC its only for java, In other cases you need to search other ways to connect to database server.